# How is angular momentum conserved when torque is zero?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

According to law of conservation of momentum , angular momentum of a particle is conserved when its torque is zero . Please make it easier for me to visualise this condition .

Comment: This is the analog of the statement that momentum is conserved when the force is zero (Newton's First Law) applied to circular motion. Torque is the equivalent of a force in circular motion. Imagine some mass rotating around a center (e.g. a planet around a star, a mass on a string). The angular momentum of this object only changes when a force is applied that is not in the radial direction, i.e. when a torque is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start with the definition of angular momentum $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$. Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ to get
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{v} \times \vec{p} + \vec{r} \times \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}
\end{equation}
The first term on the right hand side is zero because $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{p}$ are parallel to each other. Further, by Newton's second law, $d\vec{p}/dt$ is the force $\vec{F}$. We therefore have,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F} 
\end{equation}
Now, $\vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ is the torque $\vec{N}$. If the torque is zero, $\vec{L}$ is conserved.

One way to visualize it could be to notice that torque is used for turning. If it is zero, either a particle does not turn or if it is turning, it keeps turning at the same rate.

Comment: If object is at rest even then angular momentum have some value .